# How to reduce memory leak in java?

Tags: java

how  to reduce memory leaks in java application?

A memory leak in Java can occur if you forget to close a resource, or a reference to an object is not released.

Code is:

```
import java.util.Map;
public class MemLeak {
public final String key;
public MemLeak(String key) {
    this.key = key;
} 

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      Map map = System.getProperties();
      for(;;) {
         map.put(new MemLeak("key"), "value");
      }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I see no question mark in this post. What is your question?

Comment: That's not a memory *leak*. You're maintaining references to the entries you're adding. You're endlessly *consuming* memory, but it's not a leak. What's the point of this program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lets analyze a few of the the possible error messages:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: request <size> bytes for <reason>. Out of swap space?
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: <reason> <stack trace> (Native method)
```

Here’s the MemLeak class:

```
package com.post.memory.leak;

import java.util.Map;

public class MemLeak {
    public final String key;

    public MemLeak(String key) {
        this.key =key;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Map map = System.getProperties();

            for(;;) {
                map.put(new MemLeak("key"), "value");
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** the memory leak is not due to the infinite loop on line 14: the infinite loop can lead to a resource exhaustion, but not a memory leak. If we had properly implemented `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods, the code would run fine even with the infinite loop as we would only have one element inside the `HashMap`.

Answer (score 3):

*"how to reduce memory leaks in java application?"* - By not doing things like that!

Your application is attempting to build an infinite sized data structure in the heap.  The heap is fundamentally and unavoidably finite.

It won't work.

---

> A memory leak in Java can occur if you forget to close a resource, or a reference to an object is not released.

It is doubtful whether *this* application qualifies as a "memory leak".  If you did something like this by accident, then it could be described as a leak.  But your code does this with what appears to be deliberate intent.

---

I'm assuming that you understand why this builds an infinite data structure.  It is because your `MemoryLeak` class inherits `equals` and `hashcode` from `Object`.  That means that equality is the same as object identity, and hence each `MemoryLeak` instance becomes a distinct key in the map.  Hence you just keep adding more and more entries to the map until you run out of memory.